# Does VS2010 have an xml schema validator?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I am wondering does VS 2010 have something that I can use to compare an xml document to my schema? I tried a few online tools but my xml document seems to big and my browser just crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio provides design time validation and intellisense for XML. When you open an XML file you have to option of associating one of more schemas (from the properties window), which can be used to validate the file. See the documentation on the [XML Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255810.aspx) in Visual Studio. While this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302298.aspx) applies to Visual Studio 2005, it provides a graphical view of the capabilites that are present in 2005 and onwards.